# Dynamic text manipulation

Tags: javascript

In this site a have a lot of Titles( using H2 ), and a want half left then with one color and half right then with another color, separated with a space, but i cant modify the php files ( because it is a CMS ) then, i was trying to do it with some Javascript:

```
var headh2 = document.getElementsByName('head2');
    switch (headh2.innerHTML) {
        case ('first item'):
            headh2.innerHTML = '<span style="color: #022662">first </span> item';
        break;
        case ('second item'):
            headh2.innerHTML = '<span style="color: #022662">second </span> item';
        break;
        default:
            headh2.innerHTML = headh2.innerHTML;
    }
```

But, it is not does not work in any circumstance, I need to specify it, however, isnt possible to do something like this:

```
    var headh2 = document.getElementsByName('head2');
    var X = [abc]; 
    switch (headh2.innerText) {
        case (X[0]+' '+X[1]):
            headh2.innerHTML = '<span style="color: #022662">'+X[0]+'</span>'+X[1];
        break;
        case (X[0]+' '+X[1]+' '+X[2]):
            headh2.innerHTML = '<span style="color: #022662">'+X[0]+'</span>'+X[1]+' '+X[2];
        break;
        default:
            headh2.innerHTML = X[0];
    }
}
```

Where X is a range of characters without space, I tried to use a replace method:

JS:

```
    var headh2 = document.getElementsByName('head2').innerHTML;
    var str = headh2; 
    var n=str.replace(" ","</span> <span class='color2'>");
    document.getElementsByName('head2').innerHTML=n;
```

PHP:

```
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><span name="head2" class="color1"><?php the_title(); ?></span></a></h2>
```

but it doesnt work right, it replace all the spaces in the title, not just the one I want for.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: now you can see the code above. Thanks for the attention.

Comment: My answer should give you an idea, but the edits you made to your question show you doing something quite different from what you originally asked. What are you trying to change - the color of the permalink, some part of the permalink, or the color of words inside the title? Please post the HTML of the section of the page, not the PHP code.

Comment: The part that i am using with that JS is just that php part, just it, i tried to use replace with a span tag ( with some color in the style ) then, with a 2 word title it work, because i replaced the space to a '</span> <span class="color2">' , then it cancels the first span and create another with other color, and before the <a> ends there is a '</span>'. I just want to change some words's colors of the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with DOM manipulation. Note that this is slightly modified to do it to all `h2` tags:
[Live View](http://jsbin.com/aqacad/5/edit)

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('h2');
for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
{
  var second = nodes[i].firstChild;
  var parts = second.nodeValue.split(" ", 2);

  var first = document.createElement('span');
  first.appendChild(document.createTextNode(parts[0]));
  first.style.color = "#022662";
  nodes[i].insertBefore(first, second);
  if(parts.length > 1)
    second.nodeValue = " " + parts[1];
  else
    second.nodeValue = "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but, what happened with the third word?

Comment: It worked just nice, but, the problem is if i have a title with 9 spaces, i would be nice to put te separation in 5th space, not in the first, but in a 5 space title, in the 3rd space, understand? Is it possible?